# I'm scraping a FAQ pages and I need to find which tag has answers in FAQ pages

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd                     
import re
req = requests.get('https://www.godrejproperties.com/nricorner/nri-faqs')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html5lib")

ist1=[]
for elem in soup(text=re.compile(r'\s*((?:how|How|Can|can|what|What|where|Where|describe|Describe|Who|who|When|when|Why|why|Should|should|is|Is|I|Do|do|Are|are|Will|will)[^.<>?]*?\s*\?)')):
    print elem.parent
    list1.append(elem.parent)

x=str(list1[1])
tag=x[x.find("<")+1:x.find(">")]
print tag

Ques = []
for header in soup.find_all(tag):
    list_=[header]
    ffff=re.findall(r'\s*((?:how|How|Can|can|what|What|where|Where|describe|Describe|Who|who|When|when|Why|why|Should|should|is|Is|I|Do|do|Are|are|Will|will)[^.<>?]*?\s*\?)',str(list_))
    #print(ffff)
    #print (len(ffff))
    if len(ffff)>0:
        Ques.append(ffff)
Ques = np.array(Ques)
print(Ques)
```

## Similarly I need to find the answers in FAQ pages I need to create a algorithm which will capture in which tag answer is contained and get it's content and save it in a list. Later I need question and answer as a pair

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to get the details.
As you can see the html structure all the question and answers are in accordion.
So what basically we need to traverse it via the attributes.
For answers directly we can use following xpath location

> //*[@class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"]

But you need to be smart as this may lead to other accordions come to your captured data, so validate the data as per the questions id which is also reflecting in the answers id.

> //*[@class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"]

You can also use xpath or css selector Eg:

[image]

Even go through the [article](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/07/17/xpath-tips-from-the-web-scraping-trenches/)

Comment: Thanks for the ans shiv but i want to create a alogrithm which finds tha answer tag irrespective of the FAQ url i give( not only specific one url if i give some other url my alog should capture those answers as well )

Comment: @MukeshMarimuthu Do you want to **generalise** the algo for scrape?

Comment: Yes shiv I need to generalize the algo to scrape faq pages which can work for atleast few websites

Comment: @MukeshMarimuthu Then you might need to create algo in a manner which will take input as the Xpath or CSS selector and return the data within the flag available and then separate functions to process the data as it seems that different websites will have different html structures, if all are same then their is no issue

Comment: Ans=[]
for header in soup.find_all(tag):
    list_=[header]
    ffff=re.findall(r'\s*((?:how|How|Can|can|what|What|where|Where|describe|Describe|Who|who|When|when|Why|why|Should|should|is|Is|I|Do|do|Are|are|Will|will)[^.<>?]*?\s*\?)',str(list_))
    #print(ffff)
    #print (len(ffff))
    if len(ffff)>0:
        a=header.find_next('p')
        #print(a.text)
        x=a.text
        c=[x]
        x1 = [i.replace('\n', "").replace('\t', '') for i in c]
        Ans.append(x1)  
Ans = np.array(Ans)    
print(Ans)

Comment: As u see in this abve piece code i'm able to find the answers but I'm giving hard core value = "p" instead of that I need a way to find the answer tag or div with class so that I'll b able to fetch the data I tried many things but no luck.  Any help would be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: @MukeshMarimuthu Please provide the link of gist of code to check

Comment: Just copy paste the question code and the previous comment you'll get the full code which gives u question and answer.